# WooCommerce IF statements not working

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, templates

I am trying to use the WooCommerce Conditional Tags to only include a template into specific product pages. 
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/

However my statements aren't working, and they show on all pages.
I'd like to NOT display my template in a specific category and its product pages:

```
<?php 
 // Show in Shop Page OR NOT in Products IDs 15852,15859,15863,15866 OR NOT Category Archive Gift Cards

 if ( is_shop() || !is_product(array( 15852,15859,15863,15866 )) ||  !is_product_category( 'gift-cards' )) 
 { 
      get_template_part('my-template'); 
 } 
 ?>
```

I've also tried the opposite:

```
<?php 
if ( is_product(array('gift-card-25','gift-card-50','gift-card-75','gift-card-100')) ) 
{ 
    get_template_part('my-template'); 
} 
?>
```

Can you please advise how to get it to work?

Our website: https://grindersforlife.com/shop

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please show us the code source

Comment: I've fixed my question to include my code. Sorry! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my problem was to use:

`has_term( 'the-cat-I-want-to-display', 'product_cat' ) || is_product_category( 'the-cat-I-want-to-display' )`

This worked. Thanks everyone for your help!